# What's the best way to have API calls happen at different times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

In my Vue application My API calls timeout when I call them at the same time. I'm using axios and my data is going to a VueX store.

I've put my API calls in `setTimeout` methods and set them at different times to fire. It works but it seems messy and not the best way to write code. Is there a way to achieve the same effect with out the `setTimeout`, maybe `async/await`?

This is in my main component. These are called on a button click.

```
            this.$store.dispatch('undoButton', this.undoBtnAPI)
          setTimeout(() =>{
            this.$store.dispatch('getSQLData', this.apiQuery)
          }, 500)
        }, 300)
```

Here's the API call in the VueX store

```
actions: {
getSQLData (context, query) {
      console.log(query + 'query var')
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('SQL Action Called')
        console.log('query var: ' + query)
        axios.get(MS_SQL_URL + '/api/' + query)
        .then(response => {
          this.commit('initialDataUpdate', response.data.recordset)
          // console.log(response.data.map(item => item.ProcessSequence))
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.commit('completeDataLoading')
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log('SQL API error: ' + e)
          this.mssql.push(e)
        })
      }.bind(this))
},
undoButton (context, query) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios.get(MS_SQL_URL + '/api/' + query)
        .then(response => {
          this.commit('initialUndoButtonData', response.data.recordset[0]['CSN'])
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.commit('completeUndoDataLoading')
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(`SQL ERROR ${e}`)
          this.mssql.push(e)
        })
      }.bind(this))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain them with `then` and they will run one after another:

```js
   this.$store.dispatch('undoButton', this.undoBtnAPI).then(()=>{
       this.$store.dispatch('getSQLData', this.apiQuery)
   })
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I implemented the code suggested but it seems like anything in the ```then()```  doesn't get called. Here's my code: ```this.$store.dispatch('updateRecord', url)
        .then(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch('getSQLData', this.apiQuery)
        .then(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch('undoButton', this.undoBtnAPI)
          })
        })```